# CocoaPods: can my framework depend on other frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm creating a framework called `MyFramework`. This framework depends on `ZipFoundation`.
In order to test `MyFramework` I've created a new target application called `MyFrameworkShowcase`.

The workspace looks like the following:

- `MyFramework.xcworkspace`

  - `MyFramework.xcodeproj`

    - `MyFramework`
    - `MyFrameworkShowcase`
  - `Pods.xcodeproj`

The `Podfile` looks like the following:

platform :ios, '11.0'

```
target 'MyFramework' do
  use_frameworks!  
  
  pod 'ZIPFoundation', '~> 0.9'
end

target 'MyFrameworkShowcase' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  
end
```

Running the showcase app I receive the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ZIPFoundation.framework/ZIPFoundation

Any way I can adjust the `Podfile` in order to fix this issue?

Comment: [Cocoapods with Dependencies](https://ronakshah.org/How-To-Make-A-Cocoapod-With-Dependencies) It's useful to help you